# How to access private Docker repository in OpsWorks ECS Layer?

Tags: docker, chef-infra, aws-opsworks, amazon-ecs

I am trying to use an ECS Ops-Works layer to manage some automation, but I cannot figure out how to set up those instances to set up the ecs.config to contain my private Docker repository credentials, as one would do manually if managing ec2 jobs directly.  I think I need to somehow use some custom Chef to override the [setup recipe](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/opsworks_ecs/recipes/setup.rb) to load my template rather than the default template for that file, but I am new to Chef so how to do this is unclear.

Comment: you'll probably need to offer more information on the opsworks cookbook itself.  is the template resource in a recipe?  is it in a resource/provider?  can you point us at the opsworks code that you're using?  i can think of a couple of different possible solutions offhand, but having no experience with opsworks can't tell you what to do without possibly guessing a completely wrong answer...

Comment: Hi Lamont, thanks for your interest.  OpsWorks provides a set of recipes by default (https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/tree/release-chef-11.10/opsworks_ecs).  All of the recipes are applied by default, and it is up to the user to provide additional recipes (and I hope, modify existing recipes).  I am specifically interested in seeing that the https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/blob/release-chef-11.10/opsworks_ecs/recipes/setup.rb points to a different template, or reconfiguring and resetting in a custom recipe if that is not possible.

Answer (score 3):

So to restate the problem, you want to modify this template in the `opsworks_ecs::setup` recipe:

```
template "ecs.config" do
  path "/etc/ecs/ecs.config"
  source "ecs.config.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 0644
end
```

I don't know how you are 'calling' this but I'll assume for now that you're either putting this recipe directly in your run_list and/or calling it explicitly with `include_recipe "opsworks_ecs::setup"`

In that case, write a wrapper cookbook.  If you work for "Acme, Org" it might be something like `acme_opsworks_ecs::setup`.

acme_opsworks_ecs/metadata.rb should at least have:

```
name 'acme_opsworks_ecs'
version '0.0.1'

depends 'opsworks_ecs'
```

acme_opsworks_ecs/recipes/setup.rb should look like:

```
include_recipe "opsworks_ecs::setup"
resources(template: "ecs.config").cookbook(cookbook_name)
```

acme_opsworks_ecs/templates/default/ecs.config.erb is also required

```
/* add your own template content to this file -- copy theirs and edit */
```

That should allow you to fix it.  What you're doing is using Chef's two-pass parser so that the opsworks recipe defines the template resource, then you re-open it and edit it, before it actually runs.  Now, wherever you have referenced `opsworks_ecs::setup` in your run_list or include_recipe calls, replace that recipe with `acme_opsworks_ecs::setup`.

If you don't directly call `opsworks_ecs::setup`, then wrap the opsworks recipe(s) that you do call instead following the same pattern.

If you google "chef-rewind" you can find more information about this kind of pattern of using chef.  Note that the syntax that I used is built-in to chef though and does not require a custom gem install or chef_rewind resource/definition to use, so it will be substantially simpler to use the syntax in this answer.

Comment: I've subsequently been able to try this out and it didn't seem to have the intended effect.  I've subsequently been in touch with Amazon support and they have told me about some differences in their chef implementation, in particular http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/cookbooks-101-opsworks-templates.html for modifying templates.  I'll report back further when/if I get this to work.  Thanks though.

Comment: Their solution seems to rely on the multiple cookbooks path feature that we're going to eventually deprecate out of chef-client.  This chef-rewind approach is better if you can figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: If you can figure out what isn't working with this approach, I'd kind of like to know, I've re-read it a few times and I don't see any obvious mistakes I made.  Feel a little bad that you gave me +100 rep and its not working for you as well...

Comment: I think your answer was given in good faith and I feel good about rewarding the reputation.  As it stands, it looks like we're going with a different ECS manager than the OpsWorks layer.  Further, we've had some staffing changes and I'll not be the primary contact on any of this part of the system anymore, so I'm not sure I'll have occasion to work on it.  I hope other users will help you pursue this further.